# Android Java (ffmpeg-kit). Assistance(opinion) with combining 4 ffmpeg commands together

Tags: java, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I have the following 4 ffmpeg commands. 1. adds a png frame(border) over the entire length of the video. 2. creates a boomerang effect. 3. adds an outro jpeg to the last 2 seconds of the video. 4. Adds an intro jpeg to the first 2 seconds of the video.(these commands work individually)

My aim is to combine all of these individual commands into one command to create a complete edited video. The final video needs all these elements in one final edited video.

Your assistance is greatly appreciated.

```
/**
 *

 * (Middle overlay filter) String exe = "-i " + input_video_uri + " -framerate 60 -i " + frame + " -filter_complex [0]pad="+mVideoWidth+":"+mVideoHeight+":576:0[vid];[vid][1]overlay -c:a copy -vcodec mpeg4 -crf 0 -preset ultrafast -qscale 0 " + file2.getAbsolutePath();

 * (Boomerang effect) String exe = "-y -i " + input_video_uri + " -filter_complex [0]reverse[r];[0][r][0]concat=n=3,setpts=0.5*PTS " + file2.getAbsolutePath();

 * (Put image at end of video) String exe = "-i "+ input_video_uri +" -i "+ frame +" -filter_complex \"[0:v][1:v] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,"+ (msec - 2 ) + ","+ msec+")'\" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy " + file2.getAbsolutePath();

 * (Put image at start of video) String exe = "-i "+ input_video_uri +" -i "+ frame +" -filter_complex \"[0:v][1:v] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,0,2)'\" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy " + file2.getAbsolutePath();

 * */
```

Being new to ffmpeg, I am limited in knowledge. However, I have tried '&&' which produced an unrecognized error from the ffmpeg library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem in your case is to create the proper [filtergraph](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtergraph-description). I'll assist you with this task. To adapt these commands for java application is on your own.

Assumed you have four input sources:

- 0 - source video;
- 1 - middle frame image;
- 2 - title frame image;
- 3 - end frame image.

You can apply all your transformations in one `filter_complex` (for testing purposes I chose final video resolution 640x480 and source video duration 5s):

```
-filter_complex \
  "[0:v]pad=640:480:576:0[vpad]; \
   [vpad][1]overlay[vframed]; \
   [vframed]split=3[vfr1][vfr2][vfr3]; \
   [vfr1]reverse[vrev]; \
   [vfr2][vrev][vfr3]concat=n=3,setpts=0.5*PTS[vboom];
   [vboom][2]overlay=enable='lte(t,2)'[vpreout];
   [vpreout][3]overlay=enable='gte(t,5*3*0.5-2)'[vout]" \
```

Since you applied fast motion effect to "boomerang", the last line has some arithmetic to calculate duration of output video: <*5s of source video*> * <*3 boomerang's chunks*> * <*speed coefficient*>.

The result will be like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot really helpful solution. might need to add an audio file at a later stage. This works though!!!

Comment: How would one overlay an mp3 file to this ffmpeg command given in the answer?

Comment: Add the fifth input source `-i audio.mp3` and map audio stream to the output `-map 4:a`. So the full command will be like this: `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i middle_frame.png -i  title_farme.png -i end_frame.png -i audio.mp3 -filter_complex "..." -map "[vout]" -map 4:a output.mp4` Add codecs here for your choice.

Comment: thank you for the response. I keep getting an error( Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate) - String exe = "-i " + input_video_uri + " -i " + frame + " -i " + framestart + " -i " + framestart + " -i " + audioOverlay + " -filter_complex \"[0:v]pad="+mVideoWidth+":"+mVideoHeight+":576:0[vpad]; [vpad][1]overlay[vframed]; [vframed]split=3[vfr1][vfr2][vfr3]; [vfr1]reverse[vrev]; [vfr2][vrev][vfr3]concat=n=3,setpts=0.5*PTS[vboom]; [vboom][2]overlay=enable='lte(t,2)'[vpreout]; [vpreout][3]overlay=enable='gte(t,"+msec+"*3*0.5-2)'; 4:a\" " + file2.getAbsolutePath();

Comment: It's not an error, just a [warning](https://git.ffmpeg.org/gitweb/ffmpeg.git/blob/HEAD:/libavformat/demux.c#l1717) and it's not related to your original question. BTW, your exe string doesn't contain `-map "[vout]" -map` after filtergraph.

Comment: "[vout]" would fail after i removed it the command executed just fine

Comment: -i /mnt/sdcard/Movies/CameraXMovies/1669830192790.mp4 -i /mnt/sdcard/Pictures/CameraXPhotos/JSE_FRAME.png -i /mnt/sdcard/Pictures/CameraXPhotos/Start.jpeg -i /mnt/sdcard/Pictures/CameraXPhotos/Start.jpeg -filter_complex "[0:v]pad=1080:1920:576:0[vpad]; [vpad][1]overlay[vframed]; [vframed]split=3[vfr1][vfr2][vfr3]; [vfr1]reverse[vrev]; [vfr2][vrev][vfr3]concat=n=3,setpts=0.5*PTS[vboom]; [vboom][2]overlay=enable='lte(t,2)'[vpreout]; [vpreout][3]overlay=enable='gte(t,9*3*0.5-2)'[vout] "  /mnt/sdcard/Movies/CameraXMovies/filtered_1669830204783.mp4 =Error: Filter overlay has an unconnected output

Comment: Thanks, i got it working: String exe = "-i " + file + " -i " + frame + " -i " + framestart + " -i " + framestart + " -i " + audioOverlay + " -filter_complex \"[0:v]pad="+mVideoWidth+":"+mVideoHeight+":576:0[vpad]; [vpad][1]overlay[vframed]; [vframed]split=3[vfr1][vfr2][vfr3]; [vfr1]reverse[vrev]; [vfr2][vrev][vfr3]concat=n=3,setpts=0.5*PTS[vboom]; [vboom][2]overlay=enable='lte(t,2)'[vpreout]; [vpreout][3]overlay=enable='gte(t,"+msec+"*3*0.5-2)'\" -map 4:a " + file2.getAbsolutePath();

Comment: Thank you for all the help. for the setpts=0.5*PTS. thats the speed of the video. how can i speed up / slowdown the video between different timestamps. Soo between 3 and 5 seconds the video speeds up. then from 7 and 9 it slows down